# Installing Ubuntu and getting an 'Invalid Format' error message

Tags: nvidia, system-installation

(I am kind of new to Ubuntu/Linux, so sorry if this problem is already solved or is very easy to fix). Today I decided to try and install Ubuntu onto a second hard drive, so I could dual boot with Windows. Firstly, I used a USB to try and install Ubuntu; however, whenever I try and load what ever is on the USB, I get an 'Invalid Format' error message that flashes on my screen. So I then tried to use a disk instead, but to no avail. I might want to add that it does give me the options to 'Try Ubuntu', 'Install Ubuntu', and some others. However no matter what I pick it always gives me the same error...

Here is a list of my computer hardware:

CPU: Intel Core i7-4790K

GPU: Asus GeForce GTX 760

(I don't think that anything else could cause this so I skipped everything else).
My monitor, which in my opinion is what is causing this, is a LG M2232D-PZ. My monitor is connected using an HDMI cable from my GPU's HDMI port.
I will try and take some pictures of the problem, but I hope this is enough information to give you an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Try booting with nomodeset and then look to install an nvidia driver: http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/14916

Comment: Have you checked the MD5sum of your downloaded iso file with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes ? If yes, how did you copy the iso to your disk?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Select "Try Ubuntu". After the error message appears, press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`, which should take you to a command prompt. Type:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

and then press `Enter`.

This will reconfigure the X display server.